# Bootstrap Modal Carousel

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to implement the modal carousel in my simple, static, Bootstrap based HTML page. I am trying to get [this simple code](https://noreiller.github.io/bootstrap-modal-carousel/modal-carousel.html) to work in my page, but I need some more direction. I pasted the code stated into my page, but I end up with the carousel embedded in the page and not hidden. My lack of practical css/javascript knowledge is letting me down as I don't quite understand the 3 simple instructions before the code snippet.

Can somebody explain to me how I get my modal carousel working by clicking on the thumbnail in this fiddle?
[JSFiddle example here.](https://jsfiddle.net/eu2z6b64/1/)

```
   <body>
    <!--rows and cols structure -->               
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <!--2nd row-->
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">          
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                          <img src="/img/image3.jpg" alt="image3 missing">
                          <div class="caption">
                            <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                          </div>
                            </div>
                </div>
            </div>
           </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"><\/script>')</script>


    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script><!--Reference Bootstraop.min before plugins.js but after jquery.js. We alterbootstrap javascript with plugins.js -->
    <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: In your same code, you have an extra </script> towards the end.  So, quick question based on that: Are you seeing any JS errors in your debugger?

Comment: apologies, il remove that, result of me cutting out unnecessary code to ensure clarity in question

Comment: Your div structure seems incorrect!!

Answer (score -1):

If you haven't seen this one yet :

https://noreiller.github.io/bootstrap-modal-carousel/modal-carousel.html

this might give some clarity